# CS0201 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#

This code is for a clicker game.

There are 2 problems, the first one is in line 19 at `instance == this;`:

> (Error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement)

(I´m sorry, i´m new into Coding)

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class CurrencyConverter : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private static CurrencyConverter instance;
    public static CurrencyConverter Instance 
    {
        get 
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        CreateInstance ();
    }

    void CreateInstance () 
    {
        if (instance == null) 
        {
            instance == this;
        }
    }

    public string GetCurrencyIntoString(float valueToConvert)
    {
        string converted;
        if (valueToConvert >= 1000000) 
        {
            converted = (valueToConvert / 1000f).ToString("f3") + " Mil";
        } 
        else if (valueToConvert >= 1000) 
        {
            converted = (valueToConvert / 1000f).ToString("f3") + " K";
        } 
        else 
        {
            converted = ("f0") + "" + valueToConvert;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your GetCurrencyIntoString function needs to `return converted;` at the end. Your create instance method should assign to instance, and instead you are checking whether it is equal to this. Change to `instance = this;`

Comment: So, should we remember the error numbers by heart? Please [edit] your question to include a single problem with it's entire error messages. Post the second problem as a different question. One question per post.

Comment: You've misunderstood the difference between `=` -- assignment -- and `==` -- comparison for equality; a common beginner mistake. But I am more concerned with the existence of the `CreateInstance` method in the first place.  This method has a bizarre contract; you can only call it from an existing instance, and it either gives you back *itself*, or it gives you back the result of a *previous* call to `CreateInstance`. This looks like a very, very wrong attempt to write a singleton; that is, a class that can be only instantiated once.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: If that's what you're trying to do then do not make a `CreateInstance` method and certainly do not make it an instance method!  Instead you want to do something like: `public sealed class C { private static C instance = new C(); public static C Instance { get { return instance; } } private C() {} }` and then all your instance methods do not need to do anything with `instance` or `Instance`. They just operate on `this`.

Comment: There may be special things you have to do to make a singleton that derives from MonoBehavior; I do not know. You should do some research on that and see if there is a pattern specifically for MonoBehavior subclasses.

Comment: Finally, **do not use floats or doubles for currency**.  Use the `decimal` type for currency, always. Use floats and doubles for physical quantities, like length or mass. Use decimals for quantities that are measured to exact decimal places, like dollars.  (And instead of 1000f, use 1000m -- m for money.)

Answer (score 4):

At line 19, you're not using the assignment operator `=`, instead, you used the equality operator `==`.

As of the second error, since you declared a `string` return type, you need to return the *converted* string. Like this:

```
return converted;
```